# Spring MVC- Page Not Found error

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement a variant of the [muliple file upload](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multiple-file-upload-example/) tutorial, and am having an issue getting the application to run.

[image: Project structure]

I created a Spring MVC project in Eclipse using the template.

The controller has been implemented by

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayForm() {
       return "uploadForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUploadForm uploadForm, Model map) {
       //get file name and copy to server location
       return "uploadSuccess"
    }
```

where `uploadForm` and `uploadSuccess` are the JSP pages within `Views`

My web.xml file is defined as

```
<display-name>SampleFileUpload</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the `spring-servlet.xml` file is defined as

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.jasonjohns.spring.fileupload.controller" />


<bean id = "multipartResolver" class = 
    "org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean id = "jspViewResolver" class = 
    "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name = "viewClass" value = 
    "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />     
</bean>
```

However, when I start up the application no errors are found, exept the server is returning a 404 error, even when I go to `localhost:8080/SampleFileUpload/show.html`.  U'm guessing its a controller error, but I can't understand what is behind it.

Comment: Does it say that `show.html` is not available or `uploadForm.jsp`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the mapping from:

@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)

to

@RequestMapping(value = "/show.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)